# How can I process data and insert a new column by using DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

After codes

```
val df = spark.sql(sql_query)
df.show()
```

I get a schema

```
// +--------+-------+
// | id_card|   year|
// +--------+-------+
// |001_1976| 2017  |
// |015_1983| 2012  |
// |078_1963| 2011  |
// +--------+-------+
```

then I want to get a new column named `"work_year"` `(year - id_card.substring(4,8))`
I have read source code about `withColumn()` and I noticed that the column param of `withColumn` must be `org.apache.spark.sqlColumn`, not Simple String, it does upset me .

```
spark version: Spark 2.1.0 

scala version: 2.12.1

jdk version: 1.8
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `withColumn` function on the dataframe df along with a udf to get this done.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf

val df = sc.parallelize((Seq(("001_1976", 2017),("015_1983", 2012),("078_1963", 2011)))).toDF("c1", "c2")

val work_year = udf((x: String) => x.substring(4,8))

scala> df.withColumn("work_year", work_year($"c1")).show()
+--------+----+---------+
|      c1|  c2|work_year|
+--------+----+---------+
|001_1976|2017|     1976|
|015_1983|2012|     1983|
|078_1963|2011|     1963|
+--------+----+---------+
```

or use spark-sql as shown below

```
df.registerTempTable("temp_table")

scala> spark.sql("SELECT c1,c2, substring(c1,5,8) from temp_table").show()
+--------+----+-------------------+
|      c1|  c2|substring(c1, 5, 8)|
+--------+----+-------------------+
|001_1976|2017|               1976|
|015_1983|2012|               1983|
|078_1963|2011|               1963|
+--------+----+-------------------+
```

Comment: What about JAVA version, please?

Comment: java version should be irrelevant. but I would recommend atleast Java 7+

Comment: Thanks, and it works in scala!  I can't use '$' in java, how can I translate these codes to java? What would it be?

Answer (score 1):

extension to @rogue-one answer

as OP asked `work_year = (year - id_card.substring(4,8))`

then udf should be

```
val work_year = udf((x: String, y: Int) => y - x.substring(4,8).toInt)

df.withColumn("work_year", work_year($"id_card", $"year")).show()
```

output:

```
+--------+----+---------+
| id_card|year|work_year|
+--------+----+---------+
|001_1976|2017|       41|
|015_1983|2012|       29|
|078_1963|2011|       48|
+--------+----+---------+
```